# Sharing.isAvailableAsync() returns false in standalone app (Expo Sharing)

Tags: react-native, expo

When I use following code in development enviroment, it works fine. However Sharing.isAvailableAsync() return false in standalone app.

```
if (!(await Sharing.isAvailableAsync())) {
      alert(`Uh oh, sharing isn't available on your platform`);
      return;
    }
    // console.log(getImageLocalAddress);
    await Sharing.shareAsync(fileAddress, {
      mimeType: "image/jpeg",
      dialogTitle: "Share Your Result",
    });
```

Comment: can you please share from where you are importing the `Sharing` ?

Comment: Make sure you should have enable the sharing feature in while creating Standalone app.

Comment: @DipanSharma Do I need to add something to the app.json file or get user permission to use the sharing feature? https://www.codepile.net/pile/Bw356dvM